# joomla article category filter module like wordpress

Tags: joomla, filter

is there any module or component for joomla for filter-sort articles?

here is an example what is done for wordpress:
http://www.nimble3.com/portfolio-demo/

Almost every portfolio template got it:
http://wordpress-themes.derby-web-design-agency.co.uk/?theme=Alfie

Comment: Instead of linking out to demo sites, can you explain what your requirements are?

Comment: Try the core category articles module. OR look on the JED for something that does what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is called DM articles filter. Check out http://demo25.dmjoomlaextensions.com/index.php/dmcomponents/dm-articles-filter